# I want to flash MSC1211. How to do that?

Tags: 8051

I'm new to the micro-controllers, Can anyone tell me how to flash msc1211? And is it possible to program msc1211 from host pc via usb to serial data converter like TUSB3410?

links

MSC1211:  http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msc1214y5.pdf

TUSB3410: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb3410.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can flash it via Serial but for that you need to build "In-System Programmer".

MSC1211 is 8051 based microcontroller and it behaves similarly. [This link](http://www.8051projects.info/resources/usb-8051-avr-programmer.23/) can help you in designing the circuit.

With this cicuit, you can download your hex file to MSC1211.